# Burning tokens in smart contracts like uPUNK token

Tags: solidity, tokens

I'm a new in Ethereum and learning smart contracts.

In [the contract of uPUNK token](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d2bffcbb19ff14a698c424fbcdcfd17aab9b905#code) I found an internal virtual function for burning tokens:

```js
    /**
     * @dev Destroys `amount` tokens from `account`, reducing the
     * total supply.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `account` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `account` must have at least `amount` tokens.
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }
```

but I don't see any usages of it in the smart contract.

How is this function supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have contract A where your internal `_burn` function is implemented. Through inheritance in Contract B you can call the internal function in Contract A in a public function you declare in Contract B named `burn`:

```
Contract A{
// default logic

function _burn(address account, uint amount) internal virtual{
}

}


Contract B is Contract A{
//default logic

function burn(address account, uint amount) public {
_burn(account,amount);
}
}
```

You can also call it in Contract A and declare the public function there, depending on what you're looking for.https://ethereumdev.io/inheritance-in-solidity-contracts-are-classes/. This is a short example of how an internal function is used.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But what is the point to have `_burn` function in `uPUNK` token contract if that function is not called by the contract? Does it have something to do with so-called proxy contracts (I'm not familiar with this concept so far)?

Comment: As far as I've seen from the contract, the _burn function is part of the ERC20 contract. It is the flattened version so all the contracts used are shown including the functions that they have in it. That doesn't mean that you need to use all of the functions in that contract, just the ones you need. Hence, the developers from uPUNK apparently didn't need the burn function implemented.